# User stats- javascript disabled on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, iphone

I've been searching for stats on users with javascript disabled on mobile devices, but can only seem to find broad stats that don't list devices.  Does anyone know of any reliable, up to date numbers for this?

-Reason for this question, am developing a mobile site that uses javascript for easy navigation.  The site will have a fallback, just wondering how relevant this is.

Comment: I don't have any numbers but is suspect it will be very, very low, as JavaScript drives almost every part of the modern web. An internet user wouldn't last long without it.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15140/is-it-ok-to-require-certain-users-to-have-javascript-enabled) has a good discussion of whether or not you should require your users to have javascript. ["Roughly 2 percent"](https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydnfourblog/many-users-javascript-disabled-14121.html) of US users have Javascript disabled according to Yahoo. Although the stats don't seem to be established for just mobile users, less than 50% of users are on mobile on nearly any site. So we know the number is probably no higher than 4% for mobile users. (If 50% of users were mobile, and 4% of them had Javascript disabled, that would be 2% of total users, assuming no desktop users have it disabled)

Is less than 5% of users relevant? That question is up to you to consider. [Many popular sites](http://tobyho.com/2010/03/11/how-much-of-the-web-actually/) seem to have decided that those users are not relevant. Note that if you use Javascript-reliant ads as your primary source revenue, those users aren't making you money.

You should also realize that Javascript on phones can be somewhat buggy. The most prominent I've heard of involves the use of event handlers while scrolling, since scrolling is generally click and drag.

Overall, if you're worried about compatibility, you may want to create a separate website for mobile users or use a downloadable application. Having a fallback is always a good idea, if possible.